# Full (approximated) posterior covariance matrix - GPML toolbox

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, gaussian-process, posterior

I am trying to implement the paper "*[Streaming Sparse Gaussian Process Approximations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07131)*" by - Thang D. Bui, Cuong V. Nguyen, Richard E. Turner in matlab.

As a start, I create a sparse GP using the GPML toolbox which will be the basis for the Streaming Sparse GP (SSGP). I use the following GP:

```
cov     =   @covSEard;
cov_sp  =   {'apxSparse',{cov}};
mean_gp =   @meanZero;
lik     =   {@likGauss};
s       =   1;    % FITC
inf     =   @infGaussLik;
inf     =   @(varargin) inf(varargin{:},struct('s',s));
hyp.cov =   [1;1;1]
hyp.lik =   1;
hyp.xu  =   Z;    % 30 equidistant spaced inducing points
```

After hyperparameter optimalization and conditioning on the first part of my dataset, I obtain the structure `post` containing information about the approximated posterior and the predictive mean (`muPredict`) and variance (`varPredict`) (both vectors).

```
hyp =  minimize(hyp,@gp,-20,inf,mean_gp,cov_sp,lik,X_train,Y_train);
[muPredict,varPredict,~,~,~,post]  =
gp(hyp,inf,mean_gp,cov_sp,lik,X_train,Y_train,X_predict);
```

The predicted mean and variance match the training data but I would like to obtain the full posterior covariance matrix at my inducing point from the `post` structure, since I need this for the SSGP. I am able to calculate the predictive mean using the post structure by:

```
muPost = cov(hyp.cov,hyp.xu) * post.alpha;
```

which matches `muPredict` at my training data. However I fail to create a covariance matrix, which's diagonal matches `varPredict`. Any suggestions to bring me in the right direction? 
In the GPML's [manual](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/manual.pdf), page 4, calculating the approximated posterior covariance matrix is mentioned but I still seem to be doing something wrong.